# How to access the behavior that was attached to a UI element?

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties, behavior

For example, I have this:

```cs
Border myBorder = new Border();
...
designArea.Children.Add(myBorder);

ResizeAndMoveBehavior b = new ResizeAndMoveBehavior();
b.CurrentProperties = thisButtonProperties;
b.Attach(myBorder);
```

Now when I get myBorder from the designArea's children how can I access the CurrentProperties of the behavior attached to myBorder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attaching your behavior in a non-standard way, which means that there is no way to get the attached behavior(s) back later. However, if you do it the standard way, you can get this info. Here is an example of how behaviors should be managed.

```
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

// Add a behavior.
Interaction.GetBehaviors(myBorder).Add(b);

// Get all behaviors of an object.
BehaviorCollection behaviors = Interaction.GetBehaviors(myBorder);

// Get a specific type of behavior.
ResizeAndMoveBehavior myBehavior = (ResizeAndMoveBehavior)behaviors
    .Where(b => b is ResizeAndMoveBehavior).Single();
```

Comment: I'm just a begginer, so your answer helped a lot. Thank you so much.